# What does the green bar on the VisualStudio icon mean?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019.

I created a project.
I launched an otldaku.
After the debugging, a green line remained on the VisualStudio icon.

Question:
1. What does the green bar on the VisualStudio icon mean?
2. How to make this strip disappear?

[image]
[image]

---

### Update - 1

[image]

Comment: Is it doing anything in the background? Have you tried restarting it? Does it show up every time?

Comment: The green bar is a progress bar that would normally fill from left to right and can appear during a build. If it's bothering you, I'd just restart VS - unless it's actually doing something in the background.

Comment: @mxmissile See **Update - 1**. **1.** >Is it doing anything in the background? .  I do not know. How to determine this? **2.** >Have you tried restarting it?.   Yes. After restarting, the strip disappears.
But I do not want to restart VisualStudio every time. **3.** >Does it show up every time? / Yes. Only in one project.
It used to be in ASP.NET projects, but that didn’t distract me. But now I decided to figure out what was the reason.

Comment: @phuzi I would not want to restart Visual Studio after each debugging. How to determine what is running in the background?

Comment: You could just ignore it!